# PHP: Convert decimal into binary

Tags: php, binary

I'm trying to convert the number `101` to the binary `\x00\x65` and I don't know how.

I've tried this:

```
$decimal = 101;
return bin2hex(pack('S', $decimal));
```

But the result is `6500`.

The number is going to be changed and this has to be dynamical of course. Is there a way to convert it?

This has to be used to send data thru a socket (TCP/IP) using this code:

```
$socket = @fsockopen('127.0.01', '8810', $err_no, $err_str);

    if(!$socket){
        exit('Errore #'.$err_no.': '.$err_str);
    }else{
        fwrite($socket, "?B\x00\x65\x00\x01\x00\x01");
        $read = fread($socket, 255);
        return $read;
        fclose($socket);

      //    $decimal = 101;
        // return bin2hex(pack('n', $decimal));
    }
```

See the `fwrite` string I'm sending.
Sending data in different ways doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return bin2hex(pack('n', $decimal));
```

You simply have a problem with endianness. `'n'` is for *unsigned short (always 16 bit, big endian byte order)*.

Comment: Tks. That returns `0065` which is better! How do I turn it into `\x00\x65`? Tks a lot.

Comment: Do you need *literally* "\x00\x65"? Or do you need the *binary blob* whose readable hex representation would be "\x00\x65"? If the latter, what for?

Comment: You don't need "\x..". You need a binary string. Writing `"\x00\x65"` in a PHP string literal gives you a binary string. What you want is `pack('n', 101)`, which gives you the same binary string.

Comment: You are RIGHT! :D Tks

Answer (score -2):

Use following function

```
string decbin ( int $number )
```

This function will return binary number in string format. You need to pass decimal number as parameter.

For better explanation and more example just [go though php official documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.decbin.php)